# Is it good practice for a Web API to do more than CRUD operations?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, blazor, webapi, minimal-apis

I have a client (Blazor Server) application that gets data from a SQL database using a web API. My database contains a "Customers" table. My web API contains CRUD (create, read, update, delete) endpoints like these:

(Create customer) **HTTP POST** → "/api/customers"
(Read customer) **HTTP GET** → "/api/customers/{id}"
(Update customer) **HTTP PUT** → "/api/customers"
(Delete customer) **HTTP DELETE** → "/api/customers/{id}"

But I was wondering if adding endpoints like these (other than CRUD) are also good practice?

(Check if customer name exists) **HTTP GET** → "/api/customers/name-exist/{name}"
(Get customers count) **HTTP GET** → "/api/customers/count/"

Comment: If you need to expose some information from your API - you need to expose it)

Comment: It is not good practice to have the  meaningless routes. Create good action names  and add them to the route. Some controllers can have hundreds actions

Comment: @Serge what do you mean by meaningless? Checking if names exist or checking the customer count is important for my application. Would you be able to expand on your response and maybe give me an example of good action names? I am new to this and trying to learn. Thank you.

Comment: @JPGarza I mean when I  read your route I don't know what is it doing. Which of them to add the new one, with to delete and so on

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that it is good practice to satisfy the business requirements of your application. If you need to expose that information, then that's what you need to do.

But those two examples you give are not outside of the CRUD model. They are both **R**eading (or **GET**ting) information. That's entirely normal. There is no reason that is not acceptable.

The [documentation for HTTP GET](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) says:

> The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI.

That's exactly what you're doing in those two examples you give.

Comment: Okay, and how about an endpoint like this:
(get customer with all relational data/its children) HTTP GET → "/api/customers/fully/{id}"

this would be a single endpoint that returns a customer's info and also (for example) return that customer's orders, even though customers and orders are different schemas/tables under the same database. 

Is it okay to use an endpoint the return data from multiple schemas/tables under the same database?

Comment: @JPGarza If that's what you need to do to fulfill your business requirements, then why not?